# jQuery: Encontrar atributo HTML data superior a un determinado valor

Tags: html, jquery

De la misma forma que se puede utilizar el selector `$('[data-contador=9]')`, en el que el valor de `data-contador` proviene de una variable PHP `$contador`, que es siempre un entero, ¿existe algo similar a `$('[data-contador>9]')`?

Es decir, que en vez de seleccionar únicamente aquel elemento con `$contador` igual a 9, seleccione todos aquellos con `$contador` superior a 9.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Directamente no se puede con un selector de jquery, pero a ver si te vale el siguiente método con un ejemplo que he creado (a falta de ausencia de tu código).

El tema es que defino una constante `rango_min` para evaluar a partir de qué número quieres localizar los elementos, los guardo en un array secundario (equivalente a si existiera `$('[data-contador>9]')`) y ya lo siguiente son repasos para ver resultados

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    const rango_min = 9,
            $elementos_base = $("[data-contador]"),
            $superan_rango = $elementos_base.map(function(i) {
                const contador = parseInt($(this).attr("data-contador"));
                if (contador>=rango_min) {
                    return (this);
                }
            });
    
    console.log("Repaso de contadores altos...");
    $superan_rango.each(function (i,elemento) {
        console.log ("i: ",$(elemento).attr("data-contador"));
    })
    console.log( "Final! Superan el rango", $superan_rango.length, "elementos" );
});
```

Tienes el ejemplo funcionando en https://jsfiddle.net/sku62fg3/

Answer (score 0):

Gracias por tu respuesta, VFG, me ha servido como base para mi script.

Lo que quería era aplicar un ancho máximo determinado a un elemento en función del valor de `$contador`; lo he resuelto así:

```
$(function() 
{
    var elementos = $('[data-contador]');

    var array9 = [];
    var array99 = [];

    elementos.each(function()
    {
        const contador = parseInt($(this).attr('data-contador'));

        if(contador > 99) array99.push(this);
        else if(contador > 9) array9.push(this);
    })

    $(array9).each(function() {$(this).parent().siblings().children('.lista-autor-enlace').css('max-width', '425px');})
    $(array99).each(function() {$(this).parent().siblings().children('.lista-autor-enlace').css('max-width', '375px');})
});
```

Comment: De acuerdo. Me alegro de que te sirva. De todos modos, no sé si necesitas `array9` y `array99` posteriormente, pero si no es así, también puedes hacer el `$(this).parent().siblings().children('.lista-autor-enlace').css('max-width', '425px');` dentro del `if(contador > 99)` porque al final ya tienes el objeto `(this)` ahí mismo. Saludos!

Comment: Sí, en efecto, lo puedo resolver así. Gracias de nuevo.